# Ionic http session is lost after about 5 seconds. How to enable KeepAlive on ionic http post?

Tags: http, session, ionic-framework, keep-alive

I have an Ionic app that calls a website were a session is being created for the app. I can successfully issue the same call to the server 3 or 4 times in about 5 seconds and the server still recognizes the session, however after that a new session is created. Could anyone have an idea why this is happening?

btw: the session timeout on the server is 1 minute.

I am using a post operation as follows:

**this.http.post(ProductDataProvider.Server+'/mobile/AddItem',{itemstr:itemid},{ withCredentials:true})...**

Update 1: After searching it seems that I need to enable connection keep alive which might solve the problem. The issue is that I could not find a KeepAlive method or something to that effect in the documentation of Ionic Http.

Update 2: I have a way to solve this, assuming I could send the session ID to the Ionic mobile app, I could not find a way to set the session id in the post request, which i think should solve the problem.

Comment: Can you provide some code? Is this your server you're accessing? based on your update, maybe you're asking for 'Connection: keep-alive' and 'Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=1000'.

Comment: I am using asp.net with IIS - to be more precise IIS EXPRESS for debugging which is why i found this behaviour -. I am wondering how to set the Keep-Alive in ionic.